# using javascript to password protect pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf

How do I password protect a pdf using javascript? I know it's possible to apply a security policy to a pdf with javascript, but how can I get access to the login username and password?

Comment: Do you want to use [Adobe's PDF usage rights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Security_and_signatures) or are you trying to add [HTTP basic auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Example) to your HTTP server, or some custom-database-based-access-controls?

Comment: @sarnold I want to use use Adobe's usage rights, but also want to be able to manipulate the username and passwoed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use Javascript to manipulate your .pdf's ... as long as you're using Acrobat Reader.  I've used it to do bookmarks; I imagine you can also support username/password operations.

Here's the official documentation:

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/pdf/topic_js.html

This link may (or may not) also be applicable:

http://acrobatusers.com/forum/forms-livecycle-designer/protect-field-javascript/