# How to export HTML Table to password protected PDF in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First I want to export HTML table data to PDf file using  React JS or pure Javascript.
And PDF file should be password protected.
I came across libraries such as jspdf, node-qpdf and jsreport-pdf-password but not getting how to implement at client side i.e. React js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using javascript to password protect pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476184/using-javascript-to-password-protect-pdf)

Comment: @Webbanditten The provided answer has invalid link . And I want to implement using react js. I came across node-qpdf but not getting it

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.
If you are using [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) then you can use [node-qpdf](https://github.com/nrhirani/node-qpdf). This is a wrapper around qpdf which supports AES 256, AES 128, RC4 128 & RC4 40 encryption all supported by Adobe Reader.

Also You can check library you use for method like setProtection or something else like in this library [here](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_016/). There are a lot of parameters You have to check but I am sure you'll handle it :)

Comment: I want to implement it in React JS